# Comparing lists and printing a separate message in Python

Tags: python-2.7

OK so I have a 2 lists. [1,2,3,4,5] and [6,7,8,9,10].
I have to compare these two lists and print a message saying "they are different". I know how to do this:

list1, list2 = [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]
print cmp(list1, list2)

but that's not giving me the result I need. Thanks!

Comment: Homework assignment?

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

```
list1,list2 = [1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]
if cmp(list1,list2)!=0:
    print("they are diffrent")
```

Comment: Just to add clarity through documentation. 

cmp(x, y)¶

Compare the two objects x and y and return an integer according to the outcome. The return value is negative if x < y, zero if x == y and strictly positive if x > y.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!